# Writing a copy constructor for a class gives an unexpected crash while deleting object in the destructor

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

Writing a copy constructor for a class gives an unexpected crash while deleting object in the destructor. See following codes:

```
class ordinaryClass  // Sample class is used in Foo class
{
public:
    ordinaryClass(){}
};

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo():_ordinarayClass(0)
    {
        _ordinarayClass = new ordinaryClass();
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        delete _ordinarayClass; // the program crashes here when copy constructor is called.
    }

    Foo(const Foo &obj) // copy constructor
    {
        *_ordinarayClass = *obj._ordinarayClass;
    }

    Foo& operator=(const Foo& other) // copy assignment
    {
        *_ordinarayClass = *other._ordinarayClass;
        return *this;
    }

    ordinaryClass *_ordinarayClass;
};
```

In the main, If I write these codes:

```
Foo container2;
Foo container;
container = container2;
```

The program runs normally and exits normally.
But if I write it in the following way:

```
Foo container2;
Foo container = container2;
```

The program crashes while exites. I found that the program crashes at the destructor of Foo class. 
Have I made any mistakes in the copy constructor?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `*_ordinarayClass = *obj._ordinarayClass;` is invoking undefined behavior. Ask yourself what the target object's `_ordinaryClass` points to when you make that assignment.

Comment: @WhozCraig: So how am i supposed to write copy constructor and assignment for this class?

Comment: posted below. as I said in my answer, think about whether that structure must be dynamic in the first place, because from what I see, it shouldn't be, but you're closer to the code than I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your needs objects. Don't just copy pointers. I'll save the "you should be using smart pointers for this" speech, since any time spent on this site will leave you with that tattooed on your eyelids in short-order (and you should, btw use smart pointers =P)

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo() : _ordinaryClass(new ordinaryClass())
    {
    }

    virtual ~Foo()
    {
        delete _ordinaryClass;
    }

    Foo(const Foo &obj) : _ordinaryClass(new ordinaryClass(*obj._ordinaryClass))
    {
    }

    // copy/swap idiom for assignment. the value-parameter is
    //  intentional. think about what it does (hint: copy-ctor)
    Foo& operator=(Foo other)
    {
        this->swap(other);
        return *this;
    }

private:
    ordinaryClass *_ordinaryClass;

    // they get our cruft, we get theirs.
    void swap(Foo& other)
    {
        std::swap(_ordinaryClass, other._ordinaryClass);
    }
};
```

I would *seriously* reconsider whether that member should be dynamic in the first place, btw.

Comment: thanks a lot, Actually the pointer in the class is a pointer to abstract class, so  I have to declare it dynamic.

Comment: @Mosi then you likely need to template this or provide factory interfacing to it. Sorry I didn't know that ahead of time, but the general problem of the construction is going to be more complicated since this class has no idea what `_ordinaryClass` points to if it is an abstract base.

Comment: The ordinaryClass class is an abstract class and some other derived class are defined in my code. In my code I have derived the _ordinaryClass from one of the childs.

Comment: @Mosi Ah ok. then you may need a specialized constructor that takes a pointer-to-abstract-base. As I said, it is going to get more complicated regardless, but at least you have ideas now, particularly the assignment operator using copy/swap.

Comment: Yes and Thanks a lot, I thought it would be simpler ;)